# Empty gender from Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can't get the gender using the facebook explorer:

[image]

The gender attribute on the left looks like disabled, when I hover it with mouse I get `Field is empty or disallowed by the access token`. No matter permissions I enable, and no matter the API version:

[image]

I precise that the Facebook account is correctly set. Any idea ?

Comment: `user_gender` permission was introduced with API version 3.0, so you need to use at least that one for this to work.

Comment: I told that it was the same, no matter the API version. I have the same problem with 3.0+

Comment: What does the user have set as their gender? Only if it is male or female you will get a value returned; if they chose any of the other options available, then you don’t.

Comment: Yes they have sth set. In fact it seems to come from new Facebook policies. Apps need to be validated by Facebook to access to these informations ... I tried with test accounts and it works. But to get it working in production I will have to submit it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using the fb sdk v5 and Graph api greater than 3.0 it is required to use `user_gender` permission in order to obtain the gender.
For example:

**In the login url**

```
$this->helper->getLoginUrl(
           'your_return_url',
            'app_scopes' // e.g. ['email', 'user_gender']
        );
```

**In the request:**

`'/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,link,email,gender'`